# How to compare 2 list values in python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists,

```
list1_final = [
    {'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
    {'snap-id':'snp3234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
    {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'}
]

list2_all = [
    {'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': '20', 'snapname': 'abc'},
    {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': '30', 'snapname': 'def'},
    {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': '40', 'snapname': 'ght'},
    {'snap-id': 'snap1222', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
    {'snap-id': 'snp3239', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
    {'snap-id': 'snap9963', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '}
]
```

I want to compare both the list,
`list1_final` need to compare `list2_all`
if `snap-id values(snap1234)`, the particular values are matching then take all the `values(snap-id, size, snapname)` from `list2_all` and append with another list like `list3_result`.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you need help with? it is not very clear from your question.

Comment: if the answers solved your issue please consider accepting the best one to keep up community maintenance. Hope you're enjoying our community.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to extract the items from the list where 'snap-id' is the same you can iterate over the two lists and append matches to a new list.

```
list1 = [
    {'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
    {'snap-id':'snp3234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
    {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'}
]

list2 = [
    {'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': '20', 'snapname': 'abc'},
    {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': '30', 'snapname': 'def'},
    {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': '40', 'snapname': 'ght'},
    {'snap-id': 'snap1222', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
    {'snap-id': 'snp3239', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
    {'snap-id': 'snap9963', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '}
]
```

```
list3 = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i['snap-id'] == j['snap-id']:
            list3.append(j)
            break

print(list3)
```

or save the key in a set to speed up comparison as suggested by @MisterMiyagi :

```
list3 = []
set1 = set()
for i in list1:
    set1.add(i['snap-id'])

for j in list2:
    if j['snap-id'] in set1:
        list3.append(j)
print(list3)
```

I chose to save the value located in the second list as it seemed to be more complete.

Which would produce an output like this:

```
[{'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': '20', 'snapname': 'abc'}, {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': '30', 'snapname': 'def'}, {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': '40', 'snapname': 'ght'}]
```

Comment: Heads up that this is a rather inefficient O(n*m) algorithm – it will be very slow unless both lists are small. This can be done in O(n+m) instead.

Comment: I added a second solution that should improve efficacy and improved my original solution.  And you suggest an algorithm or solution which would improve efficiency @MisterMiyagi?

Comment: Hint: You need a ``set``, not a ``list``! List lookup is O(n), set lookup is O(1).

Comment: So that or is there a way to transform both dicts to set? Didn't find one that's why I chose this approach thanks @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy

list1_final = [{'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
               {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
               {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'}]

list2_all = [{'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': '20', 'snapname': 'abc'},
             {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': '30', 'snapname': 'def'},
             {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': '40', 'snapname': 'ght'},
             {'snap-id': 'snap1222', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
             {'snap-id': 'snp3239', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
             {'snap-id': 'snap9963', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '}]

out, out_2 = [], copy.deepcopy(list2_all)  # make deepcopy to save the original list2_all
# make helper dict with 'snap-id' values as keys, dicts as values
d = {v['snap-id']: v for v in out_2}
for x in list1_final:
    y = d.get(x['snap-id'], None)
    if y is not None:
        out.append(y)
        out_2.remove(y)
print('matched: ', out)  # matched
print('non-matched: ', out_2)  # non-matched
```

**Output**

```
matched:  [{'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': '20', 'snapname': 'abc'}, {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': '30', 'snapname': 'def'}, {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': '40', 'snapname': 'ght'}]
non-matched:  [{'snap-id': 'snap1222', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '}, {'snap-id': 'snp3239', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '}, {'snap-id': 'snap9963', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '}]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, and its working fine. if list1_final list if it is not matching snap-id only the list1_final values should be saved by another list. can you suggest your code

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is huge, you may have to consider using SQL or MS Access. Or fix it pythonic, then [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) comes in.

**Step 1** Convert the lists to Pandas DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd


list1_final = [{'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
               {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'},
               {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': 'NA'}]

list2_all = [{'snap-id': 'snap1234', 'size': '20', 'snapname': 'abc'},
             {'snap-id': 'snp3234', 'size': '30', 'snapname': 'def'},
             {'snap-id': 'snap9993', 'size': '40', 'snapname': 'ght'},
             {'snap-id': 'snap1222', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
             {'snap-id': 'snp3239', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '},
             {'snap-id': 'snap9963', 'size': 'NA', 'snapname': ' '}]

df_final = pd.DataFrame(list1_final)
df_all = pd.DataFrame(list2_all)
```

They'll be look like this:

`df_final`

[image: df_final]

`df_all`

[image: df_all]

**Step 2** Filter the data using **Left Join**

To **Left Join**, your choices are
[`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or
[`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).
Out this time, we'll use the former:

`df_result_raw = pd.merge(df_final, df_all, on = 'snap-id')`

[image: df_result_raw]

We don't need `blah_x`, so:

`df_result_clean = df_result_raw[['snap-id', 'size_y', 'snapname_y']]`

[image: df_result_clean]

**Step 3** If you want to save the results as CSV or MS Excel file:

CSV -> `df_result_clean.to_csv('list3_result.csv', index=False)`

Excel -> `df_result_clean.to_excel('list3_result.xlsx', index=False)`

Comment: I've noticed that the prefix of the `snap-id` are inconsistent (snap/snp). If this isn't intentional, it will cause nightmare in the future 